# Win32 Toolbar and TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I have a toolbar which doesn't wrap on WM_SIZE message to its parent. Here is create code for toolbar:

```
            // create toolbar
            g_hTool = CreateWindowEx( 0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, 
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                hWnd, ( HMENU )IDC_TEX_TOOL, GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL );

            // Send the TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE message, which is required for backward compatibility.
            SendMessage( g_hTool, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, ( WPARAM )sizeof( TBBUTTON ), 0 );
            SendMessage( g_hTool, TB_SETBUTTONSIZE, 0, MAKELPARAM( 32, 32 ) );
            SendMessage( g_hTool, TB_SETBITMAPSIZE, 0, MAKELPARAM( 32, 32 ) );
            SendMessage( g_hTool, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, ( LPARAM )TBSTYLE_EX_DRAWDDARROWS );
```

here is WM_SIZE( handled by parent window ):

```
switch( uMsg ):
{
...
case WM_SIZE:
        {
            // get auxiliary viewport toolbar window handle and autosize
            SendMessage( g_hTool, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0 );

            RECT cr;
            GetWindowRect( g_hTool, &cr );
            nTexToolHeight = cr.bottom - cr.top;

            // get status bar window handle and autosize
            SendMessage( g_hStatus, WM_SIZE, 0, 0 );

            // get status bar height
            GetWindowRect( g_hStatus, &cr );
            nTexStatusHeight = cr.bottom - cr.top;
break;
}
...
}
```

any idea why the toolbar won't wrap? The buttons extend beyond the extents of the parent window. The buttons that extend beyond the window are clipped but the toolbar isn't resized and the buttons remain unseen...

Comment: It's a bug in the control, you need to send `TB_GETIDEALSIZE` in your `WM_SIZE` handler to ask the control how high it would like to be, based on the width of your client area, and then resize it manually.

Comment: @JonathanPotter TB_GETIDEALSIZE is undeclared ... found in MSDN docs...I'm running Windows XP desktop app... what's the deal? different SDK maybe?

Comment: Make sure you `#define _WIN32_IE` to at least `0x0500`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter the getidealsize message is still not available...what value does it send?

Comment: @JonathanPotter i'm now sending (WM_USER+99). This size returned has only enough space for one row...